# How to use onPress attribute for Button in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, button, text

## this below code isn't work, please tell me whats wrong with this code?

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,Button } from 'react-native';



export default function App() {
    handle()
    {
        console.log("pressed");
    }
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>HEllo World!</Text>
            <Button variant="outlined" title = " hello" onPress={handle}></Button>
            <StatusBar style="auto" />
        </View>
           );
  
}

const st
yles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

I'm just try to print some text in console, when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

just change it to:

```
 function handle()
    {
        console.log("pressed");
    }
```

and then:

```
onPress={()=>handle()}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the working code!

you can't use function like this way

```
 handle(){
    alert('Presssed');
    console.log('pressed');
  };
```

it's not working so can use like this way

```
    const handle = () => {
    alert('Presssed');
    console.log('pressed');
  };
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const handle = () => {
    alert('Presssed');
    console.log('pressed');
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>HEllo World!</Text>
      <Button variant="outlined" title=" hello" onPress={handle}></Button>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```